# hour interval based off of a 24 clock

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure an hour interval from a start time...

So if I allow the user to choose a value between 1 and 12 I want to figure out what times that represent in a 24 hour clock.

Lets say it is 9:00AM and they want to be notified every 4 hours during that day.  I would need it to have the following values:

9AM
1PM
5PM
9PM

I'm trying to use the % (modulus) but I'm not getting what I'm expecting(`4 % 24`)...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create a `DateTime` representing the current time (9:00 AM)
- Create a `TimeSpan` representing the time interval (4 hours)
- Use [`DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx) method to produce the time of the next notification

The 12/24 hour clock does not play into it at all: you can *format* the next time the way you or your user wish - as a 24-hour clock using the `"HH:mm"` mask or as a 12-hour clock using `"hh:mm"` mask.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short code sample to get you started:

```
int hour = 9;

for (; hour <= 24; hour += 4)
   Console.WriteLine("Hour = " + hour % 12);
```

Note the use of `hour % 12`.

Answer (score 0):

Improvising... Use the % operator. As the % gets a value less than actual time (9:00AM) you know you need to change AM in PM... every time the result is less than actual time you have to change AM/PM or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int interval = 4;
    int current = 9;
    for(int i = current; i <= 24; i+=interval)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i%12 + (i > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"));
    }
```